# escape sequence

Tags: java, string, escaping

I have a html text,

```
I scored <font color="red">190</font> on MCAT!
```

, and in order to pass it as a String, I need to convert

```
<font color="red">
```

to

.  I have tried String.replace() and StringTokenizer, but I have to say I don't know how to replace " with \".

This is supposed to be quite basic.  But I can't quite know how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:  I got mixed up with the code indentations, so I tried to adjust it.  But another poster just edited my post, so I was instructed to add more text for my edition to be allowed.  Sorry!

Comment: Once value is assigned to a String variable it no longer contains " in it, unless you escaped it before assigning. So please show the code so we know where the issue is.

Comment: I have this String "I scored <font color = "red"> 190 </font> on my Mcat!", and Eclipse does not allow it to one String.

Answer (score 0):

You write `String x= "I scored <font color = \"red\"> 190 </font> on my Mcat!"`;

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 String str="I scored <font color='red'>190</font> on MCAT!"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it out.  Never use WebView.loadData(), it rarely works.